# jQuery loop after animation

Tags: jquery

I have an animated vehicle that is brought in after under 5 seconds then it comes to a stop half way along the screen where it sits behind a building.

I need to loop this animation so that once the vehicle stops if goes back to the start point and comes back in after another 5 seconds.

Here is what I have a simple function, how can I get this to loop? I tried a loop function but the animation did not run.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     setTimeout(function() {
          $('.truck2').css("left", "50%");
     }, 5000);
 });
```

Thanks for any help
GB

Answer (score 1):

I'd put the `setTimeout` inside a function and then call it from inside the `setTimeout`. This will loop without checking for an additional condition.

```
function firstAnim(){
    setTimeout(function(){
         $('.truck2').css("left", "50%");
         firstAnim(); //do it again or do something else
    }, 5000)
}
```